# Help text is not displayed for outputfield

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocksection, helptext

I have a component in which i am using outputfield to display fields. The help text is not displayed. In the same component i have inputfield and the help text is displayed fine. what could be the issue.

```
<apex:pageBlock id="CDA_Pageblock_edit" mode="maindetail" rendered="{!agreementMode == 'edit'}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="CDA_Pb_Section" columns="2">
        <apex:inputfield id="cda_request_confidential" value="{!agreementRecord.Disclosure_Type__c}"/>
        <apex:inputfield id="cda_request_confidential_comments" value="{!agreementRecord.Disclosure_Purpose__c}"/>
        <apex:inputfield id="cda_request_confidential_description" value="{!agreementRecord.Confidential_Info_Description__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="CDA_Pageblock" mode="maindetail" rendered="{!agreementMode == 'view'}">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="CDA_Pb_Section" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField id="cda_request_confidential" value="{!agreementRecord.Disclosure_Type__c}" title="{!$ObjectType.Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c.Fields.Disclosure_Type__c.InlineHelpText}"/>
        <apex:outputField id="cda_request_confidential_comments" value="{!agreementRecord.Disclosure_Purpose__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField id="cda_request_confidential_description" value="{!agreementRecord.Confidential_Info_Description__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) text if you want to specify help text.

```
<apex:pageBlock ...>
    <apex:pageBlockSection ...>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.MyField__c.inlineHelpText}">
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.MyField__c.label}" />
            <apex:inputField value="..." />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```